# Render Rails partial Forms using Nav Bar tabs in Bootstrap

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am trying to render partial forms in a page using tabs.

I have _form1.html.erb and _form2.html.erb

so my view.html.erb should render forms based on the tabbed menu

view.html.erb

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
           <li id ="one"class="active"><a href="#">form1</a></li>
           <li id="two"><a href="#">form2</a></li>
     </ul>
    <div id="one">
    <%= render partial: "form1" %>
    </div>
    <div id="two">
    <%= render partial: "form2" %>
    </div>
```

but its not working what am i doing wrong?
i am getting the error Couldn't find Project with 'project_id'=form1

Comment: your hrefs are pointing nowhere: <a href="#">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is rendering using AJAX modified my above html code as

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
           <li id ="one"class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">form1</a></li>
           <li id="two" data-toggle="tab"><a href="#">form2</a></li>
     </ul>
    <div class="tab-pane " id="one">
    <%= render partial: "form1" %>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane " id="two">
    <%= render partial: "form2" %>
    </div>
```

and created a new index.js.erb and in that

```
$("#one").html("<%= j (render 'form1') %>");
$("#two").html("<%= j (render 'form2') %>");
```

fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that you have already imported the required JavaScript file. As you can see in the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) this component rely on the Javascript:

- Activate Tab with JS:

```js
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

- Or by `data-attribute`:

```html
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I got the Tabs getting selected but the contents are showing up based on the selected tabs full contents are shown

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem. But if you are using the `data-attribute` method you have to have the `href` attribute set to the ID of the tab you want to open. In JS version you have to have something like `$('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show')` in order to open a tab with `href` value set to `#profile`.

Comment: actually when i enter plain text the texts are visible but when i want to render a partial form then both forms are displayed

Comment: that is the full code which i am trying to implement